# how to make email appear in inbox and not junk email (php)

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have written a php mail function to allow a user on my website to fill in a form and send the form to my email. as the question says the email is working once the user send the form however it only appear in my junk email folder instead, i am not a php developer but after doing some research i have noticed a lot people mentione about PHPMailer which i never heard of or used before.

i would much appreciate with a bit oh help.

```
 $to="myemail.com";

    //Errors
    $nameError="";
    $emailError="";
    $errMsg="";


    $errors="";//counting errors


    $name="";
    $email="";
    $message="";
    if(isset($_POST['send'])){


            if(empty($_POST['yourname'])){ //name field empty

                    $nameError="Please enter your name";
                    $errors++; // increament errors
            }else{

                    $name= UserInput($_POST['yourname']);

                    if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $name)){

                            $nameError="Only letters and white space accepted";
                            $errors++;
                    }

            }

            if(empty($_POST['email'])){

                    $emailError="Enter email";
                    $errors++;
            }else{

                    $email = UserInput($_POST['email']);

                    if(!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email)){

                            $emailError="Invalid Email";
                            $errors++;
                    }
            }


            if(empty($_POST['msg'])){

                    $errMsg="Enter message";
                    $errors++;
            }else{

                    $message=UserInput($_POST['msg']);
            }


            if($errors <=0){//No errors lets setup our email and send it

                     $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
                     $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
                     $headers .= 'From: <' . $email . '>' . "\r\n";


                    $text  = "<p>New Message from $name </p>";
                    $text .= "<p>Name : $name</p>";
                    $text .= "<p>Email : $email</p>";
                    $text .= "<p>Message : $message</p>";


                    mail($to, "Website Contact", $text, $headers);
                    $success="Thank your message was submitted";
                    $_POST= array(); //clearing inputs fields after success

            }


    }
```

//Filter user input

```
function UserInput($data){

        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripcslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;

}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to use phpmailer? They have an [example on github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: Your text must be full html for it to work properly, starting with the doctype type. Only correctly formatted html mails gets delivered to inbox.

Comment: You have no from address, the receiving server will mark it as spam as it is not coming from a correct address

Comment: do you any example on how to write that

Comment: $headers .= 'From: yourmail@yahoo.com' . "\r\n"; in the header

Comment: @MueyiwaMosesIkomi  is it possible for you to edit my post in case im doing summit wrong becase i tried but still nothing works

Answer (score 0):

Your using the email from their posted variable in your header. When your email server receives this it's going to look like it is spoofed because it is. Your site isn't going to be one of the mail servers setup for that domain.

When setting up MX and DNS records for email you use SPF or key signing to prove who sent the message and that it came from a trusted mail server for that domain. You may want to change the from to be an email and domain you control. You are getting their email in the body anyway.

Worst case if you don't have control over SPF records you could at least mark the from email, assuming it is something you control, as always trusted so it wouldn't go into your junk mail.

```
$headers .= 'From: <' . $to . '>' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: thanks for your comment where do i add this  variable

Comment: Replace the line in your header with the current from with the email variable

Comment: @Joel  is it possible for you to edit my post in case im doing summit wrong becase i tried but still nothing works